# How to make a MediaWiki site multilingual

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, multilingual

I've installed a MediaWiki site. I think default MediaWiki supports only one language which is configured during installation.

Is there a way in MediaWiki to support two or more languages like wikipedia.org? Available languages for a page should be listed on left side like Wikipedia, and when a user clicks a language, the version of the page in the selected language can be seen.

What is the conventional way to support multilingualism?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two different ways to make a multilingual wiki setup.

1. You can have a [family of wikis](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family) each of which supports a different language. This is how the Wikipedias work (en.wikipedia.org, ru.wikipedia.org, es.wikipedia.org, etc). This is probably what you are aiming for. Pay special attention to the section on [configuring interwiki links](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family#Scenario_4:_Multiple_wikis_sharing_common_resources) to get the links on the left hand side of the page.
2. You can create one wiki that supports multiple languages. This is how meta.wikimedia.org works. For that, you want to use the [Translate extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Translate).

**[Update 01.02.2021]** the [MediaWiki Language Extension Bundle](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_Language_Extension_Bundle) is the currently encouraged way to realize a multilingual setup, incorporating the [Translate extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Translate) as well as some other essentials that you'll end up needing anyway.

Comment: The first is difficult to set up and manage (for example you need to maintain associations between language versions of the same topic by hand, or run a python-based interwiki bot), the second gives a rather poor experience (e.g. no internationalization for category names, interface language does not follow content language). All in all, multilanguage is not exactly a strong point of MediaWiki.

Comment: an update to 2. would be to use the [MediaWiki Language Extension Bundle](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_Language_Extension_Bundle) that brings essentials and the Translate extension too. Using [MyLanguage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:Translate/Page_translation_administration#MyLanguage)-style links lets users stay in the chosen user interface language for translated page content too. Of course this promotes the idea of translations instead of independent page content per language.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way for smaller wikis is through the use of a simple template. It may not be as efficient as an extension or creating a family of wikis, which is a lot of work, but quite fast to set up.

Create a page under `Template:Otherlang` with the following code:

```
{{otherlang
|ru=Template:Otherlang:ru
}}

This template adds available translations for the page to the top through the use of flags.

To prevent issues, this template must be placed '''at the very beginning of a page'''.

Tip! When contributing a new translation to a document that already has other translations, please carry over the existing translations to the otherlang template of your contributed page. This way all multilingual pages are linked.

== Syntax ==

{{otherlang
| noborder=true (OPTIONAL)
| title=localized page display title
| lang=page:lang
| lang2=page:lang2
| etc...
}}


Warning! Do not include the language of the current page. This will only confuse readers.

=== Example ===
On a page called [[Template:Otherlang]]:

{{otherlang
| title=Template:Otherlang
| ru=Category:Programming:ru
}}


Note that:
* The language "en" is not included, as it is the language of the page that template is being used on.
* title is assigned the translated name of the page, and will appear as the display title (heading) for the page. This can replace the existing {{wrongtitle}} and {{DISPLAYTITLE}} templates currently in common use.
* The English page has no suffix.

== Available Languages ==
{| class="table table-bordered" border="2" cellpadding="7"
! Language
! Syntax
! Result
|- id="en"
|English
|en=Page_name
|[[File:En.png]]
|- id="ru"
|Russian
|ru=Page_name:ru
|[[File:Ru.png]]
|}

 {{#if: {{{title|}}} | {{DISPLAYTITLE:{{{title}}}}} }}{{#if: {{{en|}}} | '''[[File:En.png|alt=English|link={{{en}}}]]''' }} {{#if: {{{ru|}}} | [[File:Ru.png|alt=Русский|link={{{ru}}}]] }}
```

Then within each English article, paste use the following code to get a flag to show up, representing the respective language.

```
{{otherlang
| title=Tutorials/Galacticraft Getting Started Guide
| ru=Tutorials/Galacticraft_Getting_Started_Guide/ru
}}
```

An example of this can be found [here](http://wiki.micdoodle8.com/wiki/Tutorials/Galacticraft_Getting_Started_Guide). If you click on the Russian flag to the right you will find a Russian translation of the article.